# XSL key Grouping elements without keys

Tags: xslt

I want to group elements in a xml file (using XSLT 1.0). I tried it with the xsl:key function. It works fine if all elements had a key. But i have to deal with elements without a key. 
Actually the elements without a key are grouped together. But i need that if a element have no key the element is grouped to the last defined key.

I hope it becomes more obviously with my code snippets.

If the first element has no key it should be grouped to the first defined key.

Input XML

```
<position>
<item>
    <ZUZ_ID>001</ZUZ_ID>
    <BRUTTO>154.70</BRUTTO>
</item>
<item>
    <ZUZ_ID/>
    <BRUTTO>2.73</BRUTTO>
</item>
<item>
    <ZUZ_ID>002</ZUZ_ID>
    <BRUTTO>17.85</BRUTTO>
</item>
<item>
    <ZUZ_ID>001</ZUZ_ID>
    <BRUTTO>17.85</BRUTTO>
</item>
</position>
```

Actual XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="myGroup" match="item" use="normalize-space(./ZUZ_ID)"/>

  <xsl:template match="position">
    <groups>
         <xsl:for-each select="./item[count(.|key('myGroup', normalize-space(ZUZ_ID))[1]) = 1]">
               <group><xsl:value-of select="(ZUZ_ID)"/></group>
                <xsl:for-each select="key('myGroup',(ZUZ_ID))">
                   <item><xsl:value-of select="(BRUTTO)"/></item>
                </xsl:for-each>
         </xsl:for-each>
    </groups>                               
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Actual Result XML

```
<groups>
<group>001</group>
<item>154.70</item>
<item>17.85</item>
<group/>
<item>2.73</item>
<group>002</group>
<item>17.85</item>
</groups>
```

Desired Output XML

```
<groups>
<group>001</group>
<item>154.70</item>
<item>17.85</item>
<item>2.73</item>   
<group>002</group>
<item>17.85</item>
</groups>
```

Another example

```
Item 1 (ZUZID="")
Item 2 (ZUZID="1")
Item 3 (ZUZID="1")
Item 4 (ZUZID="2")
Item 5 (ZUZID="")
Item 6 (ZUZID="")
Item 7 (ZUZID="3")
```

this should be grouped to

```
Group 1 (Item 1, Item 2, Item 3)
Group 2 (Item 4, Item 5, Item 6)
Group 3 (Item 7)
```

Another example

```
Item 1 (ZUZID="")
Item 2 (ZUZID="")
```

this should be grouped to one group with all Item 1 and Item 2

Another XML Input Example

```
<position>
<item>
    <ZUZ_ID/>
    <BRUTTO>10</BRUTTO>
</item>
<item>
    <ZUZ_ID>001</ZUZ_ID>
    <BRUTTO>20</BRUTTO>
</item>
<item>
    <ZUZ_ID>001</ZUZ_ID>
    <BRUTTO>30</BRUTTO>
</item>
<item>
    <ZUZ_ID>002</ZUZ_ID>
    <BRUTTO>40</BRUTTO>
</item>
<item>
    <ZUZ_ID/>
    <BRUTTO>50</BRUTTO>
</item>
</position>
```

Desired Output

```
<groups>
   <group>001</group>
   <item>10</item>
   <item>20</item>
   <item>30</item>
   <group>002</group>
   <item>40</item>
   <item>50</item>
</groups>
```

Comment: Why would you want the item/s without a `group` value to be included in group `001`?

Comment: Because it is a functional requirement.

Comment: But what exactly is the logic here? You say "*the element is grouped to the last defined key.*" What does that mean? How do you determine what is "last defined key"?

Comment: I want to group all item elements. The grouping identifier is the value of the ZUZ_ID element. All items elements with ZUZ_ID 001 should belong to the group 001, all items with ZUZ_ID 002 should belong to the group 002,.....If there is an item element with no ZUZ_ID, this element should belong to that item with a ZUZ_ID which is the last predecessor. And if there is no predecessor whith a ZUZ_ID the item should belong to the next follower whith a ZUZ_ID......Understandable now???

Comment: I added two additional examples to the orginial question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would prefer to do this in two passes, starting by equipping each item with an ID. Then the grouping becomes simple.

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="item-by-id" match="item" use="@id"/>

<xsl:template match="/position">
    <!-- first pass  -->
    <xsl:variable name="items">
        <xsl:for-each select="item">
            <item id="{ZUZ_ID[normalize-space()] | preceding-sibling::item[normalize-space(ZUZ_ID)][1][not(normalize-space(current()/ZUZ_ID))]/ZUZ_ID | following-sibling::item[normalize-space(ZUZ_ID)][1][not(normalize-space(current()/ZUZ_ID))]/ZUZ_ID }">
                <xsl:value-of select="BRUTTO" />
            </item>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable> 
    <!-- output  -->
    <groups>
        <xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($items)/item[count(. | key('item-by-id', @id)[1]) = 1]">
            <group>
                <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
            </group>
            <xsl:for-each select="key('item-by-id', @id)">
                <item>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
               </item>
           </xsl:for-each>

        </xsl:for-each>
    </groups>                               
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Many thanks. But....I have some more desires ;-)  With the solution of Martin i was able to access all child attributes of the item element . In my simplified question i only need the BRUTTO element, but in bad real life my item element has many child elements. And i need to count them, sumarise them,....I only simplified the question because the orginial XSLT is very huge and i had only problem with the grouping.

Comment: Is there a way to access all child elements of the item element with your solution. Sorry for my beginner knowledge of XSLT. But i am just an java developer who is forced to solve a problem with XSLT......

Comment: @tomas You can copy the child elements in the first pass, by using `<xsl:copy-of select="*" />` instead of `<xsl:value-of select="BRUTTO" />`. Alternatively, you could grab the item's `generate-id()` value and use that to link to the original item via another key - but this would be a bit more complicated in XSLT 1.0.

Answer (score 1):

Your element has a key, it is the empty string, if you want to define a key based on a preceding sibling then use

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="myGroup" match="item" use="(ZUZ_ID[normalize-space()] | preceding-sibling::item[normalize-space(ZUZ_ID)]/ZUZ_ID)[last()]"/>

  <xsl:template match="position">
    <groups>
         <xsl:for-each select="./item[count(.|key('myGroup', (ZUZ_ID[normalize-space()] | preceding-sibling::item[normalize-space(ZUZ_ID)]/ZUZ_ID)[last()])[1]) = 1]">
               <group><xsl:value-of select="(ZUZ_ID)"/></group>
                <xsl:for-each select="key('myGroup',(ZUZ_ID))">
                   <item><xsl:value-of select="(BRUTTO)"/></item>
                </xsl:for-each>
         </xsl:for-each>
    </groups>                               
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note however that the order of output is

```
<groups>
   <group>001</group>
   <item>154.70</item>
   <item>2.73</item>
   <item>17.85</item>
   <group>002</group>
   <item>17.85</item>
</groups>
```

If you want to treat more cases then you can add keys for the different cases

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="myGroup"
  match="item[normalize-space(ZUZ_ID)]"
  use="ZUZ_ID"/>

<xsl:key name="myGroup"
  match="item[not(normalize-space(ZUZ_ID)) and preceding-sibling::item[normalize-space(ZUZ_ID)]]"
  use="preceding-sibling::item[normalize-space(ZUZ_ID)][1]/ZUZ_ID"/>

<xsl:key name="myGroup"
  match="item[not(normalize-space(ZUZ_ID)) and not(preceding-sibling::item[normalize-space(ZUZ_ID)])]"
  use="following-sibling::item[normalize-space(ZUZ_ID)][1]/ZUZ_ID"/>

  <xsl:template match="position">
    <groups>
         <xsl:for-each select="./item[count(.|key('myGroup', (ZUZ_ID[normalize-space()] | preceding-sibling::item[normalize-space(ZUZ_ID)]/ZUZ_ID)[last()])[1]) = 1]">
               <group><xsl:value-of select="(ZUZ_ID)"/></group>
                <xsl:for-each select="key('myGroup',(ZUZ_ID))">
                   <item><xsl:value-of select="(BRUTTO)"/></item>
                </xsl:for-each>
         </xsl:for-each>
    </groups>                               
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Untested as you did not provide any XML input samples.

Comment: Thank you. It works fine, but i have one special case: If the first element(s) had an empty key. Then this element(s) should be grouped with the first element which had a key. Hope you understand what i try to descripe...

Comment: I added two additional examples to the orginial question.

Comment: @tomas, I have added an second sample that defines the key for the different type of elements, test that yourself or provide input as XML to allow us to test.

Comment: Thank you. But unfortunately it does not work. I provide a new XML input in the orginial post.